# Binary tree merge?

Tags: java, tree, binary-search-tree

I am new to stack over flow so sorry for any mistakes, but i am trying to answer this question :

"Write a method that takes two binary trees t1, t2 and a binary tree node v as the arguments. It constructs and returns a new binary tree that has v as its root and whose left subtree is t1 and whose right subtree is t2."

I have done hours of attempts and cant seem to even make 1 binary tree.. The teacher wont really explain and wants us to do it using objects. This is the format she wants us to use.. Can someone please help me..

the commented out stuff is just my attempts to get something to work..

```
public class treeNode
{
    private  Object da;
    private treeNode left; 
    private treeNode right;
    public treeNode(Object newItem)
    {
        da = newItem; 
        left = null; 
        right = null; 
    }
    public treeNode(Object newItem, treeNode leftNode, treeNode rightNode)
    {
        da = newItem; 
        left = leftNode; 
        right = rightNode; 
    }

    public void setItem(Object newItem)
    { 
        da = newItem; 
    }
    public Object getItem() 
    { 
        return da; 
    }
    public void setLeft(treeNode leftNode)
    { 
        left = leftNode;
    }
    public treeNode getLeft() 
    { 
        return left; 
    }
    public void setRight(treeNode rightNode) 
    { 
        right = rightNode;
    }
    public treeNode getRight() 
    { 
        return right; 
    }
    //------------------------

    public void buildTree()
    {

    }   
    //public void combine (l , r)
    //{
    //  T = 5;
    //  setLeft(l);
    //  setRight(r);
    //  return T;
    //}
    //-----------------------
    public static void main (String args [])
    {
        //   treeNode a = new treeNode(5);
        //   treeNode b = new treeNode(8);
        //   treeNode c = new treeNode(2);

        //  a.setLeft(b);
        //  a.setRight(c);

        //  System.out.println(a.da);
        //  System.out.println(a.getLeft() );
        //  System.out.println(a.getRight() );



//      treeNode t = new treeNode();
//      t.left = t1;
//      t.right = t2;
//      System.out.println(buildTree(t));

    }
}
```

Comment: Just make some random trees t1 and t2. The combine part here is trivial since it is not required to resort things. (like this: `TreeNode v = new TreeNode(10, t1, t2)`)

Comment: Woops. Misread. You need to make a method. So basically nearly what you did with combine, just add a TreeNode v parameter and execute setleft and setRight the v object.

Answer (score 0):

My solution consists of two classes: Tree and Node.
The solution can be implemented with just Node, but since you were asked that the function will receive a two trees and a node so I implemented it like this. I don't know if you know java generics(The 'T' I used),  if you don't, you can use Object like the code you posted. I'm ignoring all the getters and setters, but of course you can add them.

Node class:

```
public class Node<T> {
    private T data;
    private Node right;
    private Node left;

    public Node(T data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public Node(T data, Node right, Node left) {
        this.data = data;
        this.right = right;
        this.left = left;
    }
}
```

Tree class:

```
public class Tree<T> {
    private Node<T> root;

    public Tree(Node root) {
        this.root = root;
    }

    public Node<T> getRoot() {
        return root;
    }
}
```

The combine function:

```
public Tree combine(Tree t1, Tree t2, Node v) {
    return new Tree(new Node(v, t1.getRoot(), t2.getRoot()));
}
```